# Query Binder show Cell read only when use join

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to edit records but when use query binder to join two tables in visual studio 2017, it make cells read only. It is helpful in reports but not in form where I have to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is how Visual Studio works. It only allows edits if you are only using one table. Otherwise, it cannot tell which table to update.

You have 3 choices: 1) query and edit one table at a time. 2) write some SQL to do an update one table & row at a time. 3) write some code to perform the update (again, only one table at a time).

Comment: Why the quesry in Ms Access not edited in Visual Studio query binder

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't edit MS Access queries. You have to use MS Access for that.  Visual Studio can edit data from a MS Access query, but only if that query uses only 1 table, and includes all columns from that table.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but I want to hide my MS Access front end from users thats why I use vb.net otherwise the program in MS Access work well according to the requirement. Querys are work well. I hide the hide the database by using command in load************* 'DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
'DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide************* and from options uncheck. but user can unhide it easilt you know. I want that my link tables are locked from users.

Comment: Also tell, is it possible in Visual Basic? That I want my queries run in Ms Access. Using parameter like in vb.net visual studio?